# Processing ellipse drawing over the rest and out of sync

Tags: java, processing

this code is supposed to have an ellipse with a "trail" of ellipses behind it that decrease in size and become more white. It is called "Smoke Trail" and the ellipses in this code work properly for the most part. There is one problem in the code where one of the ellipses draws over the trail and doesn't go behind like all the others. I think it has something to do with the first or last ellipse of the for loop

```
int count = 75;
int made = 0;
Smokes[] arrSmokes = new Smokes[count];
void setup()
{
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);

  if(made < count)
  {
  arrSmokes[made] = new Smokes();
  made += 1;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < made; i += 1)
   {
      arrSmokes[i].render();
   }
}

public class Smokes{
  int xCoord, yCoord;
  float size;

  Smokes()
  {
    xCoord = mouseX;
    yCoord = mouseY;
    size = 100;
  }

  void render()
  {
    noStroke();
    ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, size, size);
    size -= 4;

    if(size <= 0)
    {
      xCoord = mouseX;
      yCoord = mouseY;
      size = 100;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are keeping your old Instances of smoke and just reset them you have to store the top of your circles. Just use a Integer for that.

```
int top = 0;
```

Now you have to give every circle its number in the array...

```
if (made < count) {
    arrSmokes[made] = new Smokes(made);
    made ++;
}
/*
...
*/
int number;
Smokes(int number)
{
  this.number = number;
  //Initialyze
}
```

Now you have to change the top of your list every time you reset the Smoke particle.

```
void reset()
{
  xCoord = mouseX;
  yCoord = mouseY;
  c = 0;
  size = 100;
  top = number;
}
```

Your for-loop should now start at the entry one above the top and go the way up to the end of the array and then jump to the first entry and run until it reaches the top entry.

```
for (int i = (top+1)%count; i != top; i = (i+1)%count) {
  if (i >= made) continue;
  arrSmokes[i].render();
}
```

Since you are not allowed to change the top while executing "render();" you have to add a function "evaluate();" which you run after having done every "render();".

```
void evaluate()
{
  c += 10.2;
  size -= 4;
  if (size <= 0) {
    reset();
  }
}

void render()
{
  noStroke();
  fill(c);
  ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, size, size);
}
```

Now you should be good to go. Here is the whole source again if I messed you up a bit: https://pastebin.com/urzbzmEb

---

But I recommend to use a ArrayList instead since Java is object-based and has its own garbage-collector. The good thing at the ArrayList is you know at every time that the last object in the list is the top circle.
Here is how it would look like with an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Smokes> smokes = new ArrayList<Smokes>();

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  smokes.add(new Smokes(mouseX, mouseY));
  for (int i = 0; i < smokes.size(); i ++) {
     smokes.get(i).render(); 
  }
}

public class Smokes {
  int xCoord, yCoord;
  float size = 100, c = 0;

  Smokes(int x, int y) {
    xCoord = x;
    yCoord = y;
  }

  void render() {
    noStroke();
    fill(c);
    ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, size, size);
    c += 10.2;
    size -= 4;
    if (size <= 0) {
      smokes.remove(this);
    }
  }

}
```